# CSS - Create multiple box shadow

Tags: css, box-shadow

I have code like this

```
body {
  /*some styling for make div on center*/
}
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 7px rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.4);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zu9rd1jq/68/

I wanna make multiple box-shadow after box-shadow. It can be when we using photoshop, but how we do using css? Any idea, please :)

Comment: you cascade more shadows under `box-shadow` with `,` between check [this](https://codepen.io/sdthornton/pen/wBZdXq)

Comment: @sTx thanks for your info :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Hope you are looking for this

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: yeaah, surely. I love it ! Thank you :)